# Refreshing the Jtable is scrolling the table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

When I refresh the jtable data using custom refresh button, then the jtable scroll to a random position.
The code I used is:

```
JscrollPane jsPane = new JscrollPane();
Jtable table = new JTable();
jsPane.setViewportView(table);
getContentPane().add(jsPane, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I want jtable to maintain its viewport after refresh.
how can I achieve this?

Comment: sounds unusual - please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the behaviour

Answer (score 1):

As kleopatra said, is very wierd.
But still you can easily force:

```
int scrollPosition = scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
try {
...do the update to the table...
} finally {
    scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollPosition);
    }
}
```